# Set file association with XML with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to edit an existing an XML file with PowerShell to set a file association with group policy by pointing to this XML. I'd need to dynamically add or remove entries from this XML. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
<Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="Acrobat.Document.2017" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier=".acrobatsecuritysettings" ProgID="Acrobat.acrobatsecuritysettings" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier="acrobat" ProgId="acrobat" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
</DefaultAssociations>
```

In PowerShell I'm trying to cover the following conditions: XML file and entry exists, XML file exists but no the entry for Acrobat and the XML and entry exist:

```
$XMLPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\scripts\defaultassociations.xml"
$PackageName = 'defaultassociations'
$XMLContent = Get-Content -Path $XMLpath
$XMLContentFound1 = $XMLContent | Select-String -pattern "Acrobat.Document.2017"
$XMLContentFound2 = $XMLContent | Select-String -pattern "Acrobat.acrobatsecuritysettings"
$XMLContentFound3 = $XMLContent | Select-String -pattern '(Identifier="acrobat")'
$AcrobatAssociation = ($XMLContentFound1 -and $XMLContentFound2 -and $XMLContentFound3)


#XML exsists, Entry exsists
If($AcrobatAssociation) {
Write-Host "Acrobat association set"
}


#XML exsists, Entry DOES NOT exsists
If(!$AcrobatAssociation){
$xml=[xml](get-content $XMLPath)
}

#XML does not exsits
If(!(Test-Path -Path "$XMLPath")){

#set encoding
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

$xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($XMLPath,$encoding)
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"

$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('DefaultAssociations')

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="Acrobat.Document.2017" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017"')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Association Identifier=".acrobatsecuritysettings" ProgID="Acrobat.acrobatsecuritysettings" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017"')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Association Identifier="acrobat" ProgId="acrobat" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017"')
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()

$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()

$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
}

#Remove entry
If($AcrobatAssociation)
-> remove the entry
<Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="Acrobat.Document.2017" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier=".acrobatsecuritysettings" ProgID="Acrobat.acrobatsecuritysettings" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier="acrobat" ProgId="acrobat" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
```

Any ideas how can I manipulate the XML to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might replace the following snippet...

```
$XMLContentFound1 = $XMLContent | Select-String -pattern "Acrobat.Document.2017"
```

With something like this....

```
$xmlNode_DefaultAssoc = $xmldoc.DefaultAssociations.Association

if ( $($xmlNode_DefaultAssoc.ProgId | % { $_ -eq 'Acrobat.Document.2017' }) ) {
    $XMLContentFound1 = $true
}
```

Instead of creating an `xmlWriter` like you've done, I would probably mail it in with something like this...

```
[xml]$xmlDoc = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
<Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="Acrobat.Document.2017" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier=".acrobatsecuritysettings" ProgID="Acrobat.acrobatsecuritysettings" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
<Association Identifier="acrobat" ProgId="acrobat" ApplicationName="Adobe Acrobat 2017" />
</DefaultAssociations>
"@
```

Just to clarify, I'm not building the document through XML DOM calls. I'm just creating a big'ol string and casting it to XML.

To remove an element, I'd use something like this...

```
$xmlNode = $xmlDoc.DefaultAssociations.SelectSingleNode("Association[@ProgId='Acrobat.Document.2017']")
$xmlDoc.DefaultAssociations.RemoveChild($xmlNode)
```

You can expand on this approach for the other elements too.

Comment: thanks adam! what would be the benefit of looking for nodes with "$xmlNode_DefaultAssoc". I'm not very familiar with the whole PS world as of yet. Creating the XML using a string is a good idea, now I'm wondering as this would overwrite any existing content, how'd I add those entries withing the <DefaultAssociations> table (is it a table?!)

Comment: Taking the documents contents and doing a select-string (a grep style search), will find that string anywhere in the document. Checking the elements' attribute (using `$xmlNode_DefaultAssoc...`) will return true if the value is where you want it to be.